# A general single sql query

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table like this:

```
id | roll_no | name
---------------------
 1 |   111   | Naveed
 2 |   222   | Adil
 3 |   333   | Ali
```

**If I have data like this:**

`$fields = array( "id" , "roll_no" )` and  `$values = array( "1,111", "2,222" );`

It means I have to write a sql query to get records from table where (id != 1 and roll_no != 111) and (id != 2 and roll_no != 222). It means 3rd record will be fetched.

**If I have data like this:**

`$fields = array( "id" )` and  `$values = array( "2", "3" );`

It means I have to write a sql query to get records from table where (id != 2) and (id != 3). It means 1st record will be fetched.

**Q:** How to write a general single query using php to get data from table using above two data arrays.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from dummy where concat_ws (',', id, roll_no) not in ('1,111', '2,222')
```

Complete solution:

```
$tableName = "test"; 
$fields = array( "id" , "roll_no" );
$values = array( "1,111", "2,222" );

$fieldsStr = implode(',', $fields);
$valuesStr = implode("','", $values);
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM $tableName 
    WHERE concat_ws(',', $fieldsStr ) NOT IN ( '$valuesStr' )";
```

Comment: Remove space between `concat_ws` and `(`. It is causing this error on server: `FUNCTION CONCAT_WS does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably always have to explode the `Array` in PHP and pass the values as a string into the query ([`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)) so you probably can, and should, do all in PHP.

One thing that catches my eye is that **you are always using ID's**. Are the ID's a unique or primary field? If so just forget about the roll_no as your query will be faster using just ID's.

Comment: yes you are right. Fields are primary keys. Above logic may be implemented for different tables with different combinations of primary keys therefore I gave two data examples. I know it will include a part of php code as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Complete solution with the help of accepted answer.**

```
$tableName = "test"; 
$fields = array( "id" , "roll_no" );
$values = array( "1,111", "2,222" );

$fieldsStr = implode(',', $fields);
$valuesStr = implode("','", $values);

// Get all records from remote table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE concat_ws(',', $fieldsStr ) NOT IN ( '$valuesStr' )";
```

Comment: This answer was posted before complete solution from accepted answerer.