# MySQL: CONCAT_WS function is running on local but not on server

Tags: mysql, concat-ws

Some days ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607956/a-general-single-sql-query) about my problem and I was advised to use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function. I am using CONCAT_WS on my local mysql database and it is working perfectly. But it is not working on server(application hosted) and generate the following error.

> FUNCTION test.CONCAT_WS does not exist

Here `test` in error string is my database name on server.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM patient WHERE CONCAT_WS (',', LastName,FirstName,BirthDate ) NOT IN ('Abdul,Quddus,2000-09-30','Wasim,Akram,1993-09-12');
```

Can someone tell me the problem or suggest me another solution asked in linked question above ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it is by removing the whitespace between the function name and the parenthesis, i.e. `CONCAT_WS(...)` instead of `CONCAT_WS (...)`.

From the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions.html):

> By default, there must be no
>   whitespace between a function name and
>   the parenthesis following it. This
>   helps the MySQL parser distinguish
>   between function calls and references
>   to tables or columns that happen to
>   have the same name as a function.
>
> ...
>
> You can tell the MySQL server to
>   accept spaces after function names by
>   starting it with the
>   --sql-mode=IGNORE_SPACE option.

Also, this behavior depends on the MySQL version, this is why it works on one server and doesn't work on another, quote from the "[Function Name Parsing and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html)" manual page:

> The number of function names affected
>   by IGNORE_SPACE was reduced
>   significantly in MySQL 5.1.13, from
>   about 200 to about 30.